# how to map the columnNames to table data and show only that data in uigrid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-grid

i get `columnNames` dynamically with object inside of an property,i just want to show only that property which is inside of that object.

this is my `columnNames`

```
  $scope.columnNames=[
{"field":"firstName"},
{"field":"lastName"},
{"field":"id"},//i can get "id" or "name" or anything it comes dynamically 
{"field":"employed"}
];
```

and i get the data like this
`$scope.gridOptions.data = [
    {
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "id": "{'id':'1','name':'Syed'}",
        "employed": true
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "id": "{'id':'2','name':'Rasheed'}",
        "employed": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "id": "{'id':'3','name':'Emir'}",
        "employed": false
    }
];`

when i run this am getting the  whole object `"{'id':'3','name':'Emir'}"` in `id` column but i want only that id property value to show in that column.
and this is my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/AMeTxuMMBmfVt9f0t7HZ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JbqzsqXZeJcbnVPwil3W?p=preview)

added the following code to parse the id from json to id field

```
angular.forEach($scope.gridOptions.data, function(value, key) {
    var parsedId = angular.fromJson(value.id.replace(/'/g, '"')); 
    value.id = parsedId.id;
  });
```

also, seems like your json is ' delemited instead of ", so I had to replace the string so JSON could be parsed but if you are getting proper JSON form server you don't need to do that.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cellTemplate` in `$scope.columnNames`.

Just add `cellTemplate: '<span>{{COL_FIELD[col.field]` to `$scope.columnNames` like this:

```
  $scope.columnNames=[
      {"field":"firstName"},
      {"field":"lastName"},
      {"field":"id", cellTemplate: '<span>{{COL_FIELD[col.field]}}</span>'}, //this cellTemplate works for "id" or "name" or anything
      {"field":"employed"}
    ];
```

Since you get `$scope.columnNames` dynamically, you can add **cellTemplate** like this:

```
$scope.columnNames[2].cellTemplate='<span>{{COL_FIELD[col.field]}}</span>';
```

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QZN3OIi3x6fsNnGieJg4?p=preview)